# Get Current NT Header Data of running Process with C/C++

Tags: c++, process, header, runtime, portable-executable

this is my first post and I am stuck here. 
I am currently working on my project and I have a problem,
I am getting the baseaddress of my own module and read the process
memory to get the **IMAGE_DOS_HEADER** in **runtime**
then I continue adding **e_lanew** from the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER struct on the BaseAddress to get the **IMAGE_NT_HEADER**.
Finally, I check the NT Signature if it's valid, and it seems to be. So reading the PE of my own process worked I guess ... I am trying to read **TimeDateStamp** and this returns me 0 always and I don't know why.. here is my code

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos = {0};
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNT  = {0};    
void *BaseAddress;

// create module snapshot
MODULEENTRY32 ME32;
    HANDLE hModule  = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, GetCurrentProcessId() );
    ME32.dwSize = sizeof( ME32 );

    if( Module32First( hModule, &ME32 ) )
    {
        // get base address of my module
        BaseAddress = ME32.modBaseAddr;
    }

    CloseHandle(hModule);

// read BaseAddress and set the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER struct
if( !ReadProcessMemory( GetCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress, &pDos, sizeof( IMAGE_DOS_HEADER ), 0 ) )
        return false;

// e_magic is correct here, I skipped this

// BaseAddress + e_lfanew points to the NT Header struct, I read it here
    if( !ReadProcessMemory( GetCurrentProcess(), (void*)((unsigned long)BaseAddress + pDos.e_lfanew), &pNT, sizeof(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS), 0) )
        return false;

    if( pNT.Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE ) // this condition returns TRUE
    {
        printf("NT Header Signature is valid\n");
        printf("Timestamp: %d\n", pNT.FileHeader.TimeDateStamp); 
        // TimeDateStamp returns me 0 - why ?
    }
```

I am not sure If I forgot something - would be nice if someone could give me a hint

Thanks in advance

PS: I am sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first post :P

Comment: Does the binary have a nonzero TimeDateStamp?  (Use `dumpbin /headers myprogram.exe` to find out.)  Note that you are doing a lot of unnecessary work here.  You can get the DOS header for the current module using `__ImageBase`.  Declare as `extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;`

Comment: I am actually trying to compare the timestamp of my binary with the runtime timestamp of my running binary to detect memory modifications. I read out the timedatestamp from the "offline" binary ( which is not running ) easily, just reading the timedatestamp of my binary in runtime returns me 0. As I already said, the NT Signature returns a valid value so I am accessing correctly to the memory section I need to. I just can't figure out why I get a 0 as return If I want to read timedatestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug not sure how you missed it,

```
sizeof(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)
```

should be

```
sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS).
```